# SQL query to separate pipe delimited

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called as contents:

```
create table contents(file_name varchar2(4000), file_content clob);
```

Here is the table:

```
file_name                                  file_content
deID.RESUL_12433287659.txt_234323456.txt   |678976|TEST|TBDKK|7865679809
deID.RESUL_34534563649.txt_345353567.txt   1|678977||TB5KK|7866709
deID.RESUL_44235345636.txt_537967875.txt   |678978|TE2T|TB4KK|78669809
deID.RESUL_35234663456.txt_423452545.txt   4|678979|TE3T|T3DKK|785679809
```

I need to create another table called as data_contents using contents with the following structure:

```
file_name                                  id  number   name  address  phone
deID.RESUL_12433287659.txt_234323456.txt       678976   TEST  TBDKK    7865679809
deID.RESUL_34534563649.txt_345353567.txt    1  678977         TB5KK    7866709
deID.RESUL_44235345636.txt_537967875.txt       678978   TE2T  TB4KK    78669809
deID.RESUL_35234663456.txt_423452545.txt    4  678979   TE3T  T3DKK    785679809
```

Is there any way in SQL to separate pipe delimited and assign specific columns to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regexp_substr, and pad the rows with no id:

```
with DTE as
(
    select file_name, 
           to_char(file_content) as file_content -- preconvert the clob to a varchar
    from MyTable
)
, CTE as
(
    select file_name, 
           case 
             when substr(file_content,1,1) ='|' -- If the string starts with the delimiter
               then ' '||file_content -- then add a space at the start
             else file_content 
           end as file_content
    from DTE
)

    select file_name,
           regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 1 ) as id,
           regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 2 ) as thenumber, 
           regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 3 ) as thename,
           regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 4 ) as theaddress,
           regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 5) as phone
    from CTE
```

Comment: My file_content column is a CLOB. So, it is giving me error - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

Comment: @dang It the clob length in excess of 4000 (char)?

Comment: I am not sure, may have to check. Not sure how I can check though.

Comment: @dang select max(DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(file_content)) from MyTable

Comment: The answer to the query is 675

Comment: @dang See edit using to_char() on the clob to get the datatype sorted

Comment: if there is a blank value, then the above query does not work. For ex. if name is empty, then it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188816/discussion-between-dang-and-johnhc).